# additional-location not working with yaml formatted files

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml, application.properties, property-placeholder

In my java spring boot project, I have an **application-dev.yml** file in which there is:

```
spring:
  config:
    additional-location: classpath:*-{env}.yml
```

and another file **teacher-dev.yml** in the same path in which:

```
teacher:
  name: adam
```

With use of `@Value("${teacher.name}")`, the project is **failed** to run by the exception

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'teacher.name' in value "${teacher.name}"
```

However, it runs **OK** if I revise the **teacher-dev.yml** file as:

```
teacher.name: adam
```

I have checked the document but seems no hints there.
How do you resolve it while keeping the additional properties in yaml format to make the project work?

The spring version is 2.7.18.

Comment: Seems like it is parsing it as a .properties file, [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.x/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.yaml) states that you need `spring-boot-starter` dependency or `snake-yaml` on your project, to parse .yml files. can you verify if you have those on your classpath? You can do that with `mvn dependency:tree`
if mvn project.